# Install Valgrind on Android under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, valgrind

Hello everyone I'm trying to use valgrind on Android/Samsung sll

I followed the instructions on [this website](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-android.html) to step:

```
adb push Inst /
```

gives me error:

```
failed to copy 'Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/cg_annotate' to '/data/local/Inst/bin/cg_annotate': No such file or directory
```

the adb devices command gives me output :

```
List of devices attached
00198303580f6e    device
```

I used for :

```
CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND" \
CFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-14/arch-arm" \
./configure --prefix=/data/local/Inst \
--host=armv7-unknown-linux --target=armv7-unknown-linux \
--with-tmpdir=/sdcard
```

I am not sure where the error is because i am new to linux.

can you help me?

Thanks